# Padded_batch with pre- or post-padding option

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, padding

I have a dataset of variable-length sequences (a tensorflow TFRecord dataset) to feed an LSTM network and I want to try and compare pre- and post-padding in the batches, but current padded_batch function only pads at the sequences end. I know that we have `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` function in API but I don't know how to apply this function to dataset batch processor. The padded_batch function in tensorflow does both padding and batching, and it will find the required paddding size per batch dynamically. How can I implement this myself? My code right now is like this, and I am reading multiple TFRecord files and interleave them to make my mixed dataset:

```
featuresDict = {'data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
                'rows': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
                'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
               }

def parse_tfrecord(example):
    features = tf.parse_single_example(example, featuresDict)
    label = tf.one_hot(features['label'],N)
    rows = features['rows']
    data = tf.decode_raw(features['data'], tf.int64)
    data = tf.reshape(data, (rows,num_features)
    return data, label

def read_datasets(pattern, numFiles, numEpochs=None, batchSize=None):
    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(pattern)

    def _parse(x):
        x = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x, compression_type='GZIP')
        return x

    dataset = files.interleave(_parse, cycle_length=numFiles, block_length=1).map(parse_tfrecord)
    padded_shapes = (tf.TensorShape([None, num_features]), tf.TensorShape([N,])))
    dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batchSize, padded_shapes)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batchSize)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(numEpochs)
    return dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem like you, and I also notice that you also raise an issue on the tensorflow. I manage to solve it with `pad_sequences`, and I think I solve it right!!

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# Code snippet from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data


# Generator that generate the data
def gen_series():
    i = 0
    np.random.seed(0)
    while True:
        size = np.random.randint(0, 10)
        yield np.random.normal(size=(size, ))
        i += 1


# Transform the generator to Dataset
ds_series = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_series,
                                           output_types=(tf.float32),
                                           output_shapes=((None, )))
# output_shapes is (None, ) because the vector is unknown size

# Take first 5 samples

print("Before padding")
for vector in ds_series.take(5):
    print(vector)

print("*" * 10)


# Start to transform


def pad_session(session):
    """
        We pad the sequece in the pre-order with maxlen is 5.
        If any vector is larger than 5, we truncate the pre-sequence
    """
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
        [session.numpy()],
        maxlen=5,
        truncating="pre",
        padding='pre',
        value=0.0,
        dtype=np.float).squeeze()


def pad_map_fn(session):
    return tf.py_function(pad_session, inp=[session], Tout=(tf.float32))


padded_dataset = ds_series.map(pad_map_fn)

print("After padding")
for pre_padded_vector in padded_dataset.take(5):
    print(pre_padded_vector)
```

and will generate the following output

```
Before padding
tf.Tensor([ 0.11849646  0.1139678   0.37025538  1.0405308  -1.5169828 ], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.8662762  -0.10321885  0.41059852  0.14404356  1.4542735   0.7610377
  0.12167501  0.44386324], shape=(8,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.33367434 1.4143772 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-0.12405066  1.1682731   0.94718593], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-2.5529897], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
**********
After padding
tf.Tensor([ 0.11849646  0.1139678   0.37025538  1.0405308  -1.5169828 ], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.14404356 1.4542735  0.7610377  0.12167501 0.44386324], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.         0.         0.         0.33367434 1.4143772 ], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([ 0.          0.         -0.12405066  1.1682731   0.94718593], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([ 0.         0.         0.         0.        -2.5529897], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

I want to get your attention into the `pad_session`, we pass the sequence `[session.numpy]` into `pad_sequences` because we need to pass 2-d array into it.

Maybe there is a better way to solve it, but here's the answer that I get.

Hope it will help you!!!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my case, I don't know the max_len because it is changing in each batch of when dataset is fetched for the next batch. Padded_batch function have access to this data but I don't. I don't want to pad a whole dataset, I want to pad it batch by batch.

Comment: why do you need tf.py_function?